# git commit does not open editor

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have a problem in which whenever I run git commit this shows up:

```
error: cannot spawn subl: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'subl'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

`subl` is an alias for sublime. I am running git Bash on Win10.
If I just run '`subl`', it opens the editor without a  problem, but with git commit it doesn't. Here is my git config file:

```
[core]
    editor = subl -w -n
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Execute `git config --global core.editor "\"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe\" %*"` to configure Sublime as your editor in Windows.

EDIT: The above assumes you have Sublime 3 installed. If you have Sublime 2 installed, change the full path to the correct valid path to sublime_text.exe.

Comment: Doesn't git-bash use UNIX-style file paths? Would it recognize Windows file paths?

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 w/ Git Bash.

Comment: it seems that when invoking the path, git doesn't recognize the spaces. C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe -w -n: C:/Program: No such file or directory . Adding \ before spaces doesn't work either (fatal: bad config line 4 in file C:/Users/Lucas/.gitconfig
) – Lucas Rebelo 8 mins ago

Comment: @LucasRebelo Try running `git config --global core.editor "\"c:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe\" %*"` from your git bash.

Answer (score 2):

Shell aliases are a feature of the shell and not of the operating system. They can therefore only be executed directly by the shell, and not through any external tools like `git`.

For the same reason you can not use aliases with `find -exec`, `xargs` or `sudo`.

If you want a shorter way to run something that also works with external tools, create a shell script with that name instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the whole path to `subl` like `/usr/local/bin/subl` or whatever it is on your system. You can find out by executing `which subl` in your terminal.

It's possible that whatever env your git is running in, it's not aware of your aliases.